# How to install Keras if the required version of setuptools is older than default?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, pip, anaconda, conda

I'm using conda 4.4.9. I have already installed TensorFlow and I want to install Keras as well.

Then I tried to activate my virtual environment and install Keras as below:-

```
activate tensorflow_env_001
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade keras
```

Then I got the following error message:

```
tensorflow 1.9.0 has requirement setuptools<=39.1.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.2.0 which is incompatible
```

That means my `setuptools` is too new. In fact, I can run the TensorFlow codes without any error. But I just can't install Keras. I tried to update `setuptools` but that had just made the situation worse, as `setuptools` now become `40.0.0`.

If I run `conda list`, and I will see this:-

[image]

That means all `TensorFlow`, `Keras` and `setuptools` are here. But when I tried to import `Keras` in my Python code, I just got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'`.

How can I properly install Keras? Many thanks!!

Comment: Use `tf.keras` that comes with tensorflow.

Comment: you could try `conda install setuptools=39.1.0` although I found personally this didn't work for me

Answer (score 13):

> tensorflow 1.9.0 has requirement setuptools<=39.1.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.2.0 which is incompatible

i got same error.To downgrade your setuptools version you can use

```
pip install setuptools==39.1.0
```

hope this helps further for keras installations.

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove the env

> conda remove --name ENVNAME --all

Then create a new one but first upgrade the pip version

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip

and then install tensorflow:

> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.9.0

It will automatically get (downgrade) your version of setuptools

```
    #
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
    .......
    python                    3.5.6                he025d50_0
    setuptools                39.1.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    six                       1.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    tensorboard               1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    tensorflow                1.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    .....
```